# VB6 ADODC control properties Connection string, won't work on other PCs need user path name

Tags: vb6

for VB6 / Visual Basic 6
Below is the connection string entered in properties for ADODC control on my form.  The problem is this will not work on other computers.

ConnectionString property
PROVIDER=Microsoft.Jet.OLEDB.4.0;Data Source = c:\Documents and Settings\Daniel\My Documents\TM100\data\database.mdb;

I already have a strUserPath variable that I have created that works for my  text data files throughout the program...is it possible to use the same variable.  I tried the & userpath & but not sure if the property window for the control can accept a variable.

Comment: Configure through odbc

Comment: You cant use variables in the Properties Window but you can do it in code via `yourADODCControl.ConnectionString = a & b`

Comment: Did the comment from @AlexK. help? That seems like the right approach

Comment: Putting that connection string in form_load doesn't do anything,  not sure where to insert that.